# What has replaced the deprecated __proto__ in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to work out how to instantiate a new object from another instantiated object without without using the new operator. The following code below works but I hear the __proto__ property is depreciated.

```
var MyObject = function( arg ) {

    this.value = arg;

};

MyObject.prototype.getValue = function() {

    return this.value;

};

// Standard way of instantiating an object
var object1 = new MyObject( 'foo' );

// Creating new object based on another without using new operator
var object2 = {};
object2.__proto__ = object1.__proto__
object1.constructor.call( object2, 'bar' );

console.log( object1 );
console.log( object2 );
```

So how would I do this without the __proto__ property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [thefourtheye mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22831097/1903116), changing the [[Prototype]] of an object after it is created is strongly discourged.

However, in your use case you don't really have a reason to change the [[Prototype]] at a random point in an object's lifetime, but instead you want to create an object with a given [[Prototype]].

The method that accomplishes this is [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), which creates an object with a specified [[Prototype]] value:

```
var object2 = Object.create(object1);
object1.constructor.call(object2, 'bar');
```

If your desired environment doesn't support Object.create, a shim is available on the MDN page. While imperfect (not all functionality is covered), the shim does exactly what you need in this scenario.

Comment: I had been looking at Object.create but from the examples on MDN it only looked like it was there to duplicate object definitions not instances. I hate that website... I always have trouble understanding something they have written. Thank you for lending your expertise!

Answer (score 8):

Quoting from [`__proto__`'s MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto#Summary),

> The `__proto__` property is deprecated and should not be used. [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) should be used instead of the `__proto__` getter to determine the [[Prototype]] of an object.  Mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object, no matter how this is accomplished, is strongly discouraged, because it is very slow and unavoidably slows down subsequent execution in modern JavaScript implementations.  However, [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) is provided in ES6 as a very-slightly-preferred alternative to the `__proto__` setter.

But your actual code works, let us see why.

1. First of all, any object which is created with an Object literal will have its `__proto__` property as the same as `Object.prototype`. You can check this like this

   ```
   var object2 = {};
   console.log(object2.__proto__ === Object.prototype);
   # true
   ```
2. Since `object1` is created with `MyObject` function, the following is true

   ```
   console.log(object1.__proto__ === MyObject.prototype);
   # true
   ```
3. When you say

   ```
   object2.__proto__ = object1.__proto__;
   ```

   From 2, we can see that it is the same as,

   ```
   object2.__proto__ = MyObject.prototype;
   ```

   so, you are just making JavaScript believe that, `object2` is also an object of `MyObject`.
4. Since we assigned `MyObject`'s prototype to `object1`'s prototype, `constructor` of both the objects are the same

   ```
   console.log(object1.constructor === object2.constructor);
   ```
5. And then you are calling the `MyObject` function with `object2` as `this`.

   ```
   object1.constructor.call( object2, 'bar' );
   ```

Since changing `__proto__` is NOT recommended, the best way to do this would be to use `new` keyword only

```
var object1 = new MyObject('foo'),
    object2 = new MyObject('bar');
```

But, lets say you have got only `object1`, but not the definition of `MyObject`. Then, you can make use of the `constructor` property like this

```
object2 = new object1.constructor('bar');
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears the latest draft of ECMAScript 6 has standardized `__proto__`. See section B.2.2.1 of https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html.

Comment: …as a deprecated legacy feature, yes.